# Eclipse android IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, android, eclipse

currently i dont know what im doing wrong here is my sample code please help me

Problem:

```
02-28 03:41:51.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8431): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 95, size is 90
02-28 03:41:51.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8431):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
02-28 03:41:51.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8431):     at com.example.finalpro.ThirdQuiz$1.onClick(ThirdQuiz.java:248
02-28 03:41:51.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8431):     at com.example.finalpro.ThirdQuiz.showNextQuiz(ThirdQuiz.java:194)
```

02-28 03:41:51.750: E/AndroidRuntime(8431):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)

Now my Java :

```
   public class ThirdQuiz extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView countLabel;
    private TextView questionLabel;
    private Button answerBtn1;
    private Button answerBtn2;
    private Button answerBtn3;
    private Button answerBtn4;

    private String rightAnswer;
    private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
    private int quizCount = 1;
    static final private int QUIZ_COUNT = 25;
    int quizCategory = 0;

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

    String quizData[][] = {
            // {"Country", "Right Answer", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"}
            {"Feed me and I live, yet give me a drink and I die", "Fire"," Ice ","Hot","Cold"}  ,
            {"I fly without wings, I cry without eyes. What am I", " Clouds"," Rain ","Rainbow ","Sun"},
            {"You can see me in water, but I never get wet. What am I?", " A reflection"," Mirror","Wall","BlackBoard"},
            {"What belongs to you but others use it more than you do?", " Your name"," Your NickName","Your LastName"," Your UserName"},
            {"What 4-letter word can be written forward, backward or upside down, and can still be read from left to right?", " NOON"," Moon","Four","Dead"},
            {"What runs around the whole yard without moving?", " A fence"," Wall","Board"," Table"},
            {"What kind of table can you eat?", " Vegetable"," Meat","Fruits"," Chicken"},
            {"What's orange and sounds like a parrot?", " A carrot","Banana","Meat"," Potato"},
            {"Which is the most curious letter?", " Y?","A?","B?"," X?"},
            {"What does the big tomato say to the small tomato?", " Ketchup","Mang Thomas","Datu Puti","Silver Swan"},
            {"What begins with T, ends with T and has T in it?", " Teapot","Team Potatot","Tilt","Talt"},
            {"People buy me to eat, but never eat me. What am I?", "Plates and cuttlery","My Friends","Food","Junk Food"},
            {"The more you take, the more you leave behind. What am I?", "Footsteps","Slow Motion","At the back","Hiding"},
            {"A blue house has blue bricks; a yellow house has a yellow bricks. What is a green house made of?", "Glass","Grass","Wall","Door"},
            {"Railroad crossing without any cars. Can you spell that without any R’s?", "Thats","Why","Where","How"},
            {"What kind of dog keeps the best time?", "Watchdog","Watch Anime","Watch Cartoons","Watch Actions"},
            {"You can do this with your friends. You can do this with your nose. But don't do it with your friend's nose!", "Pick","Touch","Watch","Move"},
            {"What is it something that you always have but you always leave behind?", "Fingerprints","Footprints","Faceprints","Bodyprints"},
            {"How can you physically stand behind your father while he is standing behind you?", "Stand back to back","Following me","Stay","Istalker"},
            {"There was a plane crash every single person died. Who survived?", "Married couples","Single Parents","Single","RelationShip"},
            {"What does no man want, yet no man want to lose?", "His job","His Family","Important to me"," His RelationShip"},
            {"This company makes billions of dollars selling Windows.", "Microsoft","Google","PowerPoint"," Microsoft Office"},
            {"What language does a billboard speak?", " Sign language"," Rain ","Rainbow ","Sun"} ,
            {"What does this mean? Wondealicerland", "Alice in wonderland"," Batman ","Superman ","SpiderMan"} ,
            {"Which ring is square?", "A boxing ring","Basketball Court ","Volleyball Court ","Class Room"} ,
            {"What US state is surrounded by the most water?", "Hawaii"," Canada ","America ","Hongkong"} ,
            {"Three times what number is no larger than two times that same number?", "0"," 2 ","4","6"} ,
            {"Which of Santa's reindeer can you see in outer space?", "Comet"," Asteroid ","Meteors","Planet"} ,
            {"What gets tighter when stretched?", "A budget"," Exercise ","Hungry","Waster"} ,
            {"When set loose I fly away, Never so cursed As when I go astray.", "A fart"," hungry ","Hurry","Sleepy"} ,
            {"Everyone has me but nobody can lose me. What am I?", "A shadow"," A friend ","Family","Enemy"} ,
            {"Fashions change but what can a person wear that is never out of style?", "A smile"," Sad ","Angry","Ugly"},
            {"A kind of tree can you carry in your hand?", "A palm"," Foot ","Ears","Touch"} ,
            {"What can you catch but not throw?", "A cold"," Sad ","Angry","Ugly"} ,
            {"What sits in a corner while travelling all around the world?", "Stamp"," Hi ","Signature","Messages"} ,
            {"I'm flat when I'm new. I'm fat when you use me. I release my gas when something sharp touches me. What am I?", "A balloon"," Mirror","Picture","Selfie"}, 
            {"I am a king who’s good at measuring stuff. What am I?", "Ruler"," Ball Pen ","Eraser","Pencil"}, 
            {"Which word contains 26 letters but only three syllables?", "Alphabet"," Letters ","Spelling","Direction"} , 
            {"What can you hear but not touch or see and yet control?", "Your voice"," Moving ","Stay","Go away"} , 
            {"What did the thief get for stealing the calendar?", "12 Months"," 10 Months ","11 Months","8 Months"}  ,
            {"Before Mt. Everest was discovered as the highest mountain in the world, which mountain was the highest?", "Mt Everest"," Mt k2 ","Mt Makalu","Mr Panaslu"}  ,
            {"howers bring may flowers, what do may flowers bring?", "Pilgrims"," Ball Pen ","Eraser","Pencil"}  ,
            {"What did Adam say the day before Christmas?", "It's Christmas, Eve!"," New Year ","Birthday","Reunion"}  ,
            {"What kind of fish chases a mouse?", "Catfish"," Dog ","Horse","Bird"}  ,
            {"What has four legs, but can't walk?", "A table"," Board ","Chair","Pencil"}  ,
            {"What is always slow to come, but never actually happens?", "Tomorrow"," Yesterday ","Later","After Noon"} , 
            {"If you blow past your destination, you'll have to throw your car into this."," Reverse ","Force","Move","Walk"},
            {"What has a mouth but can't chew?", "River"," Road ","Air","Inside"}  ,
            {"David's father has three sons: Snap, Crackle, and ?","David"," Angel ","Mico","Klein"} , 
            {"What has a ring, but no finger?", "Phone"," Laptop ","Computer","Tablet"},
            {"You play with me at night before going to sleep. You can’t get caught fiddling with me at work. You only let a select few people touch me. What am I?","Phone","pillow","blanket","toys"},
            {" What’s a four-letter word that ends in “k” and means the same as intercourse?","Talk","seek","peek","weak"},
            {" I start with a “v” and every woman has one. She can even use me to get what she wants. What am I?","voice.","vase","vein","verse"},
            {" I come in a lot of different sizes. Sometimes, I drip a little. If you blow me, it feels really good. What am I?","nose.","mout","ears","eyes"},
            {".What’s in a man’s pants that you won’t find in a girl’s dress?","Pockets","stripes","buttons","zipper"},
            {"You stick your poles inside me. You tie me down to get me up. I get wet before you do. What am I?","tent.","house","barbique","rope"},
            {"What’s long and hard and has cum in it?","cucumber","egg plant","bittergourd","bottlegourd"},
            {" If I miss, I might hit your bush. It’s my job to stuff your box. When I come, it’s news. What am I?","newspaperboy","reporter","tv","radio"},
            {" What four-letter word begins with “f” and ends with “k,” and if you can’t get it you can always just use your hands?"," fork","fowk","feek","flak"},
            {" All day long it’s in and out. I discharge loads from my shaft. Both men and women go down on me. What am I?","elevator","escalator","stairs","ladders"},
            {"I’m spread out before being eaten. Your tongue gets me off. People sometimes lick my nuts. What am I?","Peanut butter.","jelly","ketchup","mayonnaise"},
            {"Arnold Schwarzenegger’s is really long. Michael J. Fox’s is short. Daffy Duck’s isn’t human. Madonna doesn’t have one. What am I?","last name","first name","middle name","nickname"},
            {"What is hard and hairy on the outside, soft and wet on the inside? The word begins with “c,” ends in “t,”.","coconut.","coat","cat","carrot"},
            {"I start with a “p” and ends with “n” and I’m a major player in the film industry. What am I?","popcorn","person","penguin","putin"},
            {"My business is briefs. I’m a cunning linguist. I plead and plead for it regularly. What am I?","lawyer","judge","police","governor"},
            {"You get a lot of it if you’re powerful and successful, but significantly less when you’re just starting out. You sometimes do it with yourself, but it’s a lot better when you do it with another person. What am I talking about?","email","chat","text","mail"},
            {"I have a stiff shaft. My tip penetrates. I come with a quiver. What am I?","arrow","javellin","bullet","rocket"},
            {"I go in hard but come out soft, and I never mind if you want to blow me. What am I?","bubblegum","clay","paper","cement"},
            {"What does a dog do that a man steps into?","pants","shorts","shirt","underwear"},
            {"I’m great for protection. You use your fingers to get me off. What am I?","gloves","cloth","shield","ring"},
            {"What gets longer if pulled, fits snugly between breasts, slides neatly into a hole, chokes people when used incorrectly, and works well when jerked?","seatbelt","belt","tie","sash"},
            {"What’s beautiful and natural, but gets prickly if it isn’t trimmed regularly?","lawn","park","tree","hair"},
            {"All men have one, but it’s longer on some than others. The Pope never uses his, and a man gives it to his wife once they’re married.","last name","first name","middle name","nickname"},
            {"I assist with erections. Sometimes, giant balls hang from me. I’m known as a big swinger. What am I?","crane","wrecking ball","giant arm","hook"},
            {"You find me in a guy’s pants. I’m about six inches long, I have a head, and some women love to blow me. What am I?","twenty dollar bill","credit card","check","ID"},
            {"When I go in, I can cause some pain. I’ll fill your holes when you ask me to. I also ask that you spit, and not swallow. What am I?","dentist","Dermatologists ","Endocrinologists ","Colon and Rectal Surgeons "},
            {"I grow in a bed, first white then red, and the plumper I get, the better women like me. What am I?","strawberry.","raspberries"," blueberries"," blackcurrants"},
            {"I’m the highlight of many dates. I’m especially responsive when you put your fingers deep inside me. What am I?","bowling ball","basketball","baseball","soccer"},
            {"What’s made of rubber, handed out at some schools, and exists to prevent mistakes?","Erasers","pencils","chalk","paper"},
            {"I’m at least six inches long. I love it wet and foamy when I get to do my job. What am I?","toothbrush.","comb","brush","sponge"},
            {"Over 1,000 people went down on me. I wasn’t a maiden for long. Something really big and hard ripped me open. What am I?","titanic","train to busan","snake on a plane","fast and furious"},
            {"It’s a fun thing to do and you devote a significant amount of energy to thinking about it, but you hate knowing that your parents are doing it. What is it?","facebook","twitter","instagram","youtube"},
            {"What’s most useful when it’s long and hard?","education","patience","relationship","trust"},
            {"What’s white, sticky, and better to spit than to swallow?","toothpaste","glue","mayonnaise","milk"},
            {"A lot of people like these to be as long as possible, but short ones can be effective, and it’s definitely possible for them to be too long. What are they?","tweets","cooments","reply","post"},
            {"Name a word that’s four letters long, ends in “u-n-t” and is used to refer to some women?","aunt","uncle","grandmother","grandfather"},
            {"What does a woman have two of the a cow has four of?","legs","arms","foot","toe"},
            {"What goes up, lets out a load, and then goes back down?","elevator","bus","plane","rocket"},
            {"If you put three fingers into these holes, it's gonna be a shocker. What am I talking about?","power outlet","window","bowlingball holes","ears"},
            {"Some people prefer being on top, others prefer being on the bottom, and it always involves a bed.","bunk bed","floor","bedroom","bedrock"},
            {"What goes naked to keep you warm?","sheep","cow","chicken","fish"},
            {"What does a gay horse eat?","haaaay","grass","leaves","fish"},
            {"If there is H2O on the inside of a fire hydrant, what is on the outside? ","K9P","CuTe","SiLi","h2"},
            {"What word starts with ''c'' and ends with ''t'' and is synonymous with pussy?","cat","chicken","crow","cow"},
            {"what is tall when it's young and short when old?","candle","pole","building","statue"},

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third_quiz);

        countLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
        questionLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
        answerBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtn1);
        answerBtn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtn2);
        answerBtn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtn3);
        answerBtn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtn4);
        Typeface font3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "GrinchedRegular.otf");  
        countLabel.setTypeface(font3);
        questionLabel.setTypeface(font3);
        answerBtn1.setTypeface(font3);
        answerBtn2.setTypeface(font3);
        answerBtn3.setTypeface(font3);
        answerBtn4.setTypeface(font3);


        //Receive from StartuActivitu
         quizCategory = getIntent().getIntExtra("QUIZ_CATEGORY",0);
        Log.v("CATEGORY_TAG", quizCategory + "");

        // Create quizArray from quizData.
        for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {
            // Prepare array.
            ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]);  // Country
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]);  // Right Answer
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]);  // Choice1
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][3]);  // Choice2
            tmpArray.add(quizData[i][4]);  // Choice3

            // Add tmpArray to quizArray.
            quizArray.add(tmpArray);
        }

        showNextQuiz();

    }

    public void showNextQuiz() {

        // Update quizCountLabel.
        countLabel.setText("Q" + quizCount);

        // Generate random number between 0 and 14 (quizArray's size - 1).
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum= 0;
        if(quizCategory==0){
            randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());
        }
        else if (quizCategory==1){
            randomNum = random.nextInt(50 - 0) + 0 ;
        }
        else if (quizCategory==2){
            randomNum= random.nextInt(100 - 50) + 50;
        }
        else {
            randomNum= random.nextInt(150 - 100)+100;
        }

        // Pick one quiz set.
        ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

        // Set question and right answer.
        // Array format: {"Country", "Right Answer", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"}
        questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
        rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

        // Remove "Country" from quiz and Shuffle choices.
        quiz.remove(0);
        Collections.shuffle(quiz);

        // Set Choices.
        answerBtn1.setText(quiz.get(0));
        answerBtn2.setText(quiz.get(1));
        answerBtn3.setText(quiz.get(2));
        answerBtn4.setText(quiz.get(3));

        // Remove this quiz from quizArray.
        quizArray.remove(randomNum);

    }

    public void checkAnswer(View view) {

        // Get pushed button.
        Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
        String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

        String alertTitle;

        if (btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
            // Correct!
            alertTitle = "Correct!";
            rightAnswerCount++;
        } else {
            // Wrong...
            alertTitle = "Wrong...";
        }

        // Create Dialog.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
        builder.setMessage("Answer : " + rightAnswer);
        builder.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT) {
                    // Show Result.
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", rightAnswerCount);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    quizCount++;
                    showNextQuiz();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }
    }
```

Lastly let me add that i havent put the last details on index 100-150 our if fits realy index sorry if im stupid or sound stupid im fairly new ot this im really sorry.

Comment: Where is your `ThirdQuiz.java`  ?

Comment: Oh my god im sorry wrong Java

Comment: My ThirdQuiz.java is the same as this one

Comment: but let me edit it

Comment: most likely your randomNum is bigger than yoru list size. Based on the exception , the list has elements up to 90th index, but you are accessing 95th. For that range, I believe it is for quizCategory 2, . for 3 it looks like it will be from 100-150. Your list needs to have content on those index.

Comment: i think my problem is that im generating a random Num from a given range and as i have a RNG i did a code that removes some of the arrays so it wont pop up again

Comment: should ijust remove the Index remover?

Comment: I can not suggest you how to apply your logic. But before accessing/removing list , you need to make sure your index is within the range of your arraylist.

Comment: yes currently my index is withing range the problem is that i remove some of those index by quiz.remove im sorry if i dont make sense to you ive been learning this stuff like a month or two

Comment: when you remove the size decreases , so the available index too.  Use the size of list to determine your next randomNum within its range if possible. Based on your implementation , it seems like you need some extra variable to identify the quiz type. If that is true, I suggest you to use POJO instead of multiDimen array.